# Join list into subclass and list<subclass>

Tags: c#, linq, join, subclass

My Classes:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : BaseModel
{
    public Int32 field1 { get; set; }
    public Int32 field2 { get; set; }

    public ClassB NameB { get; set; }
    public List<ClassC> NameC { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : BaseModel
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    ...
}   

public class ClassC : BaseModel
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

then i have:

`List<ClassA> listA = getAllClassA(); //with null values for ClassB and ClassC
List<ClassB> listB = getAllClassB();
List<ClassC> listC = getAllClassC();`

how to join the list "b" and " c" using LINQ , within the "A" list using the BaseModel ID as joint parameter ?

I know there's a way to do this using foreach but I don't know if it's the best way ...

EX: using foreach

```
foreach (var item in listA)
{
    item.NameB = ListB.Where(w => w.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    foreach (var c in ListC.Where(w => w.ID == item.ID)
    {
        item.NameC.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "join"? Are you really talking about the relational algebra join, or are you going for an union or something? What have you tried?

Comment: i need to join (like SQL) using the ID from basemodel

foreach(var item in listA)
{
     item.NameB.add(ListB.Where(w=>w.id == item.id).FirstorDefault());
}

Comment: Okay. Are you having trouble with the `Join` method (or the `join` keyword)? Did you follow the documentation?

Comment: Are you pulling this data from a DB via EF?  If so, can you show what your get methods do.  You probably want one Linq query against your DB instead of joining in memory.

Comment: I use base.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ClassA>("PROC_A @ID_PESQUISA", sqlParam) to get the values of each list...

Comment: I updated the question with an example using foreach I wonder is there a better way to do using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

**Edit**

```
foreach (var item in listA)
{
    item.NameB = ListB.Where(w => w.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();        
    item.NameC = ListC.Where(w => w.ID == item.ID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: this will probably work but wanted to try using LINQ Query instead of foreach